# numpy vectorize an 5x5 array but allow any changes made in the 5x5 array to reflect in the vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have an array (5x5) called A, and vector which I obtain by concatenation. The following code shows the two arrays of interest. However, my problem is, I am having difficulty making any changes that i make to A, reflect in b without having to loop over the concatenation. This is what I have so far:

```
        A = np.array((np.arange(5), np.arange(5), np.arange(5), np.arange(5)))
        b = np.concatenate(a, axis=None)
        print("This is what A looks like before a change in values",A)
        for i in range(2):
           A[i,1] = 100
        print("This is what A looks like after change in values",A,b)
```

I want the values of `b` to change when I update the values from A. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Use `b=A.ravel()`

Comment: @QuangHoang There is still another problem. Lets say in the for loop, A is updated entirely, I notice that b does not change. Here is an example of what I mean: `def array_create(x):
    return [np.arange(x)]*4
a = np.array(array_create(5))
b = a.ravel()

print(a)
for i in range(2,3):
    a = np.array(array_create(i)) 
    
print(b,a)`

Answer (score 1):

To get a flattened view, use `b = A.ravel()` (as suggested by Quang Hoang in the comments).

As for this code which you added in a comment:

```
def array_create(x):
    return [np.arange(x)]*4

a = np.array(array_create(5))
b = a.ravel()
print(a)
for i in range(2,3):
    a = np.array(array_create(i))
print(b,a)
```

The problem is that you are "rebinding" the name `a` to new objects each time through the loop.  To instead replace the *contents* of `a` and have the changes appear in `b` as well, do this:

```
for i in range(2,3):
    a[:] = np.array(array_create(i))
```

Assigning to `a[:]` replaces the values, rather than making the variable name refer to something new.